# angular: passing data to $resource service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi there I write a service of $resource for connecting the api. 
here is the code in service.js

```
.factory('selfApi2', function ($resource, localStorageService) {
var AB = {
  data: function (apiURL, header, data, params) {
    return $resource("http://localhost:4000/api" + apiURL, null, {
      update: {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: header,
        data: data,
        params: params
      }
    });
  }
};
return AB;
})
```

in my controller.js

```
var header = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
var myData = {
'phone': '12345678'
};
selfApi2.data('/tableName',header,{where:{"name":"kevin"}).update(myData, function(result){
console.log("update Kevin's phone succeed",result);
})
```

it works. But why the variable myData should put inside the update() part rather than the data() part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the `data()` is a function which will just create a `ReST` resource which would expose `rest` apis `get save query remove delete` as default.

So in this `data()` call you are just creating the rest resources. Passing `myData` with this function would not make any sense. The data() call would return the `Resource` instance which will have your `update` api function which accepts the parameters.

And, passing your data at api construction time does not make sense.

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) is the complete reference

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because "data" is a function that returns object of $resource.
Try the scenario below:

```
    // service
    .factory('api', function ($resource) {
      var api = {};

      api.issues = $resource("http://localhost:4000/api/issues");

      api.users = $resource("http://localhost:4000/api/users", {}, {
        update: {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        },
      });

      return api;
    })

    // controller
    api.users
      .update({where:{name:'kevin'}})
      .$promise.then(function(success) {
        // DO SOMETHING
      });

    ...

    api.issues.query().$promise.then(
      function(success) {
        // DO SOMETHING
      });
```